# When I reverse the order in the triple integral with cylindrical coordinates, I get different volumes

Tags: integration, cylindrical-coordinates

I want to compute the mass of the region between the sphere \begin{equation} x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 9 \end{equation}
and the hyperboloid
\begin{equation}
x^2 + y^2 - z^2 = 1
\end{equation}
for $z \geq 0$ and with density $\rho(x,y,z)=z $

[Solid Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1FUg.png)

When I calculate this with triple integrals in cylindrical coordinates, I get
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{5}} \int_{\sqrt{r^2-1}}^{\sqrt{9-r^2}} z.r \, dz \, dr \, d\theta = \frac{25\pi}{2}
\end{equation}

But if I reverse the order, putting $r$ before $z$ and splitting into two regions:
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{1+z^2}} z.r \, dr \, dz \, d\theta + \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{2}^{3} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{9-z^2}} z.r \, dr \, dz \, d\theta = \frac{49\pi}{4}
\end{equation}

Why did I get that difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $r < 1$, the lower terminal of the $\mathrm{d}z$ integral should be $0$, not $\sqrt{r^2 - 1}$ (which isn't even real).
The correct form of the first version of the triple integral is
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\sqrt{5}} \int_{\sqrt{\max\{r^2-1, 0\}}}^{\sqrt{9 - r^2}} rz\, \mathrm{d}z\, \mathrm{d} r\, \mathrm{d}\theta,
$$
which indeed is $49\pi/4$.